# MVC 4 - How can I load a View using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am pretty new to MVC and JavaScript. I have a dropdown ('ProcessGroupRevisions') on a View and when the user selects a certain item in the drop down, I want to execute an action in a controller that will render a new view. I have the following code which is sort of stubbed out. But I know it's not right (because it doesn't work), but I'm not sure what I need to do to make it work.

```
        // This handles the onchange for the Revisions dropdown.
        $("#ProcessGroupRevisions").change(function () {
            if ($("#ProcessGroupRevisions").prop("value") == "-1") {
                '@Url.Action("AddNewRevision", "SetpointManagement", new RouteValueDictionary { { "processGroupId", ViewBag.ProcessGroupId } })';
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you put the code snippet above in a *.cshtml file, it will work, right?

Comment: if you are new to javascript, then you should **NOT** be using frameworks/libraries before you have learned the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use the jquery load method:

```
$('#yourContainer').load('/ControllerName/ActionName');
```

"yourContainer" must in this case be the ID of the HTML element which you want to use as a container for your view. You may also want to have some extra logic to avoid having that hard-coded URL to the controller there. In that case you can do something like this:

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")'

$("#yourContainer").load(baseUrl + "ControllerName/ActionName");
```

Note that the baseUrl variable must be defined in your CSHTML file and not in a separate js file, because it must be handled on the server-side.

Comment: Thank you. What does '#yourContainer' represent?

Comment: The element you want the results of your Action to go into. You'll need an empty <div> on your page somewhere waiting to accept this content when your dropdown changes.

Comment: Ok, but I wanted to load a completely new View, replacing the current View in the browser.

Comment: If you want to "replace the current view", it sounds like you actually want to navigate to a new page. In that case you can just do this instead:

window.location.href = baseUrl + "ControllerName/ActionName"; 

,where baseUrl is what I described in the original post. This would be the equivalent of clicking on a link pointing at your new view.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry posted accidentally before I was finished the first time.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#ProcessGroupRevisions").change(function () {
            if ($("#ProcessGroupRevisions :selected").val() == "-1") {
                var url = '@Url.Action("AddNewRevision", "SetpointManagement")';
                //To load the view via AJAX
                $("#GroupRevisionDetails").load(url, new {processGroupId: $("#ProcessGroupRevisions :selected").val()});
                //To load the view and replace the current page
                window.location.href = url + "?processGroupId=" + $("#ProcessGroupRevisions :selected").val();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<select id="ProcessGroupRevisions">
    <option value="-1">-- Pick One --<option>
    <option value="1">Group Revision 1<option>
    <option value="2">Group Revision 2<option>
    <option value="3">Group Revision 3<option>
    <option value="4">Group Revision 4<option>
</select>

<div id="GroupRevisionDetails"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `window.location`

For eg.

```
window.location = "/ControllerName/ActionName";
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me exactly how that would look included in the code I originally included?

Comment: you would need to replace your line "URL.Action..." with the one I provided. For adding any parameters you can use the query string method i.e. adding parameters after adding a question mark.

Comment: `window.location = "/ControllerName/ActionName?processGroupId=" + "@ViewBag.ProcessGroupId";`
Let me know if it works.